# Can I install Ubuntu 12.10 on an hp desktop that has UEFI

Tags: installation, 12.10, hp, uefi, secure-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system)

I just bought a new computer and it has windows 8 but I don't like windows 8 and wanted to use ubuntu 12.10 and am wondering if this is possible to do because of UEFI.  It is an hp pavilion p6-2376.

Comment: I managed to install 12.10 with UEFI. As for 12.04, you would have to use legacy boot.

Comment: is your computer 32 or 64 bit? I am not sure but I think 32 bit ubuntu does not have EFI support, yet. Also 12.10 has it and 12.04 not.

Comment: My computer can support both 32 and 64 bit.  I will download the 64 bit and burn it to a dvd and try it.  Is there something that I have to do because my computer already has windows 8 installed or can I just boot to the ubuntu cd and overwrite windows 8

Comment: Try using a USB stick (faster than CD/DVD), but initially run Ubuntu *alongside* (using LiveCD) to **test**.

Comment: I did the live but I just get a black screen.  I tried the 64 bit.  Can someone help me with this and why its happening?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that post

Answer (score 0):

UEFI is not an impediment to installing Ubuntu 12.10. Contrary to one comment, it's not an impediment for 12.04, either, or even several earlier versions -- but Ubuntu's UEFI support has improved with recent releases, so it's better in 12.10 than in 12.04.

That said, you may need to do things differently than you would on a BIOS-based computer. Windows 8 machines also usually ship with Secure Boot enabled, which can cause problems. (This is an area in which 12.10 is supposedly better than 12.04, but I've seen a few problem reports even with 12.10, so you may have to disable Secure Boot in your firmware.)

I've heard that the image file used to distribute Ubuntu boots successfully in EFI mode from CD, but not when burned to USB drive. I ran across instructions for adapting it recently, but I didn't save the URL, so I'm afraid I can't point you to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that with secure boot enabled, Ubuntu will install but may still fail to boot.

To disable UEFI secure boot:

go to the Charms Bar in Windows 8 and select Settings > Change PC Settings > General > Advanced Start Up. On the next screen select Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > UEFI Firmware Settings (this option is available only on new Windows 8 machines). 
(from: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2015107/downgrading-from-windows-8-to-7-what-you-need-to-know.html?page=2)

On my HP Pavilion laptop, I run Ubuntu in VMware Player since when installed under Wubi or to a partition, the fan runs non-stop and the cpu gets too hot.